# Why am I not getting the complete date in M/D/YYYY with DateTime.Now.ToString method?

Tags: c#

I am using the `DateTime.Now.ToString` method with the format `M/D/YYYY` but am not getting the desired output.  Instead, I'm getting `9/D/YYYY`.  Please help.  Currently, my code snippet is as below:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now.Date;
            string Date = d.ToString("M/D/YYYY");
```

Comment: There is no format specifier as `D`, but `d`. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: Same die Y, use y instead

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`D` and `YYYY` are not valid format specifiers; specifiers are case sensitive. Use `M/d/yyyy` instead.

[Have a look at MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You should really let us know what your expected output is.

Regardless, the format strings are case sensitive. `YYYY` and `D` mean nothing.

[Take a look at the MSDN article here about it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

What you are probably expecting though, is this:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now.Date;
string Date = d.ToString("M/d/yyyy"); // 9/9/2013
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

or if you want avoid '0' before one digit numbers, use this:

```
DateTime.Today.ToString("M/d/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;

string s = d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

Response.Write(s);
```

hope it may helpful

Answer (score 0):

the date format is case sensitive. try using M/d/yyyy format